# MySQL stored procedure should not run and return "invalid entry" error message if entry does not meet certain criteria. How to do it?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following table `book` -

```
+--------+------+------------------------------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
| BookId | ISBN | book_name                    | author | ed_num | price | pages |
+--------+------+------------------------------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
|      1 |    1 | Glimpses of the past         |      1 |      1 |   650 |   396 |
|      2 |    2 | Beyond The Horizons of Venus |      1 |      1 |   670 |   396 |
|      3 |    3 | Ultrasonic Aquaculture       |      2 |      1 |   799 |   500 |
|      4 |    4 | Cyrogenic Engines            |      2 |      1 |   499 |   330 |
+--------+------+------------------------------+--------+--------+-------+-------+
```

It has the following structure -

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| BookId    | int         | NO   | UNI | NULL    |       |
| ISBN      | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| book_name | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| author    | int         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| ed_num    | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price     | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| pages     | int         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Now I write a procedure that updates the price and returns how much short the price is from 1000.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS price_short_of_thousand_after_update; //
CREATE PROCEDURE price_short_of_thousand_after_update(
    IN my_ISBN INT,
    INOUT my_price INT
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE price_temp INT;

    UPDATE book
        SET price = my_price
        WHERE ISBN = my_ISBN;
    
    SELECT price FROM book
        WHERE ISBN = my_ISBN
        INTO price_temp;
        
    SET my_price = 1000 - price_temp;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

A few runs -

```
SET @ISBN = 1;
SET @price = 890;

CALL price_short_of_thousand_after_update(@ISBN, @price);

SELECT @price;
+--------+
| @price |
+--------+
|    110 |
+--------+

SET @price = 999;
CALL price_short_of_thousand_after_update(@ISBN, @price);

SELECT @price;
+--------+
| @price |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+

SET @price = 1000;
CALL price_short_of_thousand_after_update(@ISBN, @price);

SELECT @price;
+--------+
| @price |
+--------+
|      0 |
+--------+

SET @price = 1001;
CALL price_short_of_thousand_after_update(@ISBN, @price);

SELECT @price;
+--------+
| @price |
+--------+
|     -1 |
+--------+
```

Now, I want to write my stored procedure in such a way that if `@price` is set at a value that is greater than 1000, then the procedure does not run and returns error message that -

"Invalid entry, price cannot be greater than 1000"

How can I do so?

Comment: `IF my_price  > 1000 THEN ....`

Comment: What part of it are you having trouble with? It's a simple `IF` statement that should signal an error.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want the the program to run and exit with an error message if the condition is true. What is the command to do so?

Comment: The `SIGNAL` statement is used to signal an error. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html

Comment: Ok, thank you, didn't know about SIGNAL and RESIGNAL. Only question in `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'` what does `45000` mean?

Comment: From that page: To signal a generic SQLSTATE value, use '45000', which means “unhandled user-defined exception.”